# System service display error at the time of start

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace cloud_sync
{
public partial class cloud_sync : ServiceBase
{
    public cloud_sync()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ec2\\ec2.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\My cloud\VM Instances\");
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                File.Delete(filePath);
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/ec2/temp.txt");

                if (new FileInfo("c:/ec2/temp.txt").Length > 0)
                {
                    string line, temp, temp1;
                    string[] content = new string[4];
                    line = GetWord(sr);
                    line = GetWord(sr);
                    string[] terms = line.ToLower().Trim().Split('\t');

                    Console.WriteLine(terms[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(terms[5]);
                    Console.WriteLine(terms[9]);
                    temp1 = terms[1];
                    content[0] = "Instance_id :" + terms[1];
                    content[1] = "Status :" + terms[5];
                    content[2] = "Type :" + terms[9];
                    if (terms[5].Equals("terminated"))
                    {
                        line = GetWord(sr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = GetWord(sr);
                        line = GetWord(sr);
                    }



                    terms = line.ToLower().Trim().Split('\t');
                    Console.WriteLine(terms[4]);
                    content[3] = "Name :" + terms[4];
                    int i = terms[4].Length;

                    temp = "c:/My cloud/VM Instances/" + temp1 + " (" + terms[4] + ")";
                    temp = temp + ".cvm";
                    File.WriteAllLines(temp, content);


                    while ((line = GetWord(sr)) != null)
                    {
                        line = GetWord(sr);
                        terms = line.ToLower().Trim().Split('\t');

                        Console.WriteLine(terms[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine(terms[5]);
                        Console.WriteLine(terms[9]);
                        temp1 = terms[1];
                        content[0] = "Instance_id :" + terms[1];
                        content[1] = "Status :" + terms[5];
                        content[2] = "Type :" + terms[9];
                        if (terms[5].Equals("terminated"))
                        {
                            line = GetWord(sr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            line = GetWord(sr);
                            line = GetWord(sr);
                        }

                        terms = line.ToLower().Trim().Split('\t');
                        Console.WriteLine(terms[4]);
                        content[3] = "Name :" + terms[4];
                        i = terms[4].Length;

                        temp = "c:/My cloud/VM Instances/" + temp1 + " (" + terms[4] + ")";
                        temp = temp + ".cvm";
                        File.WriteAllLines(temp, content);
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
                File.Delete("c:/ec2/temp.txt");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

   static string GetWord(StreamReader sr)
    {
        return sr.ReadLine();
    }

}    
}
```

I have written this system service but when I start this service, it show me error **"Windows could not start the cloud_sync service on local computer. Error: 1053 the service did not respond to start and control request in timely fashion. "**
and after pressing ok its status become "starting". Please tell what is the problem with this.
I am greenhorn in c#, this is my first system service.
please help me out of this

Comment: Console.WriteLine is ignored in widows services, use EventLog.WriteEntry and log exceptions in Windows event log

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving `Windows could not start the cloud_sync service on local computer. Error: 1053 the service did not respond to start and control request in timely fashion` because your `OnStart()` is not returning.  You need to spin off another thread to execute your desired code.

```
private Task _serviceTask;
private bool _stop;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _serviceTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeTask) 
}

// Rename the method from SomeTask to something that makes more sense
private static void SomeTask()
{
    // Move your code here
}
```

You should replace your `while(true)` to `while(!_stop)` so that you can gracefully end the loop within `OnStop()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it. But i didnt get your last line "You should replace your while(true) to while(!_stop) so that you can gracefully end the loop within OnStop()".

How to end loop within onstop() ?

Comment: @manish, when your service is requested to stop, `OnStop()` is called.  Ideally, your `OnStop()` method should terminate your loop. Right now you seem to be looping forever.

Comment: How can i do that? I mean how can i terminate loop in  OnStop() function?

Comment: That's my point exactly. With your current code, you can't; however, if you loop on a variable, then within the `OnStop()` function, you can set the variable `_stop` to true, which will result in the loop condition evaluating to false.